# Some problems in planning a trip to Tunisia

Tags: trains, buses, planning, africa, tunisia

I was planning a trip to Tunisia in September, but I've encountered some issues. My plan is to arrive in Tunis, stay there for a few days, then take a bus or a train to Tozeur, spend a few days there, move on to Monastir, and take a flight back home from there.

However, I've run into some problems. The first is that there are two ways to get from Tunis to Tozeur: by train or by bus. Many online sources recommend the bus, but I don't understand why. Is traveling by train really that bad? Also, I haven't been able to find the prices for either the train or bus routes online, or where I can buy the tickets. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Additionally, I'm not sure whether to stay in Monastir or in the nearby city of Sousse. Can anyone tell me if there are price differences between staying in Monastir or Sousse? And which of the two cities has the most beautiful beaches?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Pretty sure why the bus is recommanded is that the train network must be unreliable or that much slower

Comment: To check the trains and schedules https://www.sncft.com.tn/en

Comment: @NeanDerThal but the costs of the routes are not written there or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo It seems that calling them is the only way (+216 71 334 444)

Comment: Don't overlook the [Louage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louage) or shared taxi-bus as used in very many countries of the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. how to get to tozeur?

the train system is inefficient and often late. my recommendation is the take another form of transportation called louage. you can take it from Tunis (monsef bey station -- "محطة سيارات ألجرة لواج "المنصف باي--according to this [source](http://www.commune-tunis.gov.tn/publish/images/transport/LOUAGESTATION.pdf)) to Tozeur for 27.3TND according to this [source](http://www.transport.tn/uploads/tarif/Tunis.pdf) (تونس - توزر 27300)

you can buy the ticket from the booth in the station (they don't take resevations)

2. where to stay

monastir and sousse, both have great beaches and a lot of places to go. In terms of resorts and hotels, they both have amazing options. for monastir they have a beach resort area that is slightly secluded from the city if you want to enjoy some quiet time with less crowded beaches. the commute to the city isn't very long and the city, in general, is less expensive. as for sousse, you can enjoy the closeness to the city and the convenient transportation within the city but if you are closer to the touristic area, the beaches will be more crowded (the city is generally more expensive).
sousse can open for you the option to travel through ennfidha airport though which you can consider if you haven't booked yet.